# Bootstrap input form elements overlapping container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The website in question is: http://openreachmarketing.co.uk/index.php

Though the `<input>` elements have the following CSS rule applied, they are still overlapping the blue containing element `.well` which has `padding:20px` set.

```
#myform input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `<input>` elements do not seem to be honouring the 20px worth of padding on the right side of the `.well` container.

Is there a reason this is happening? I was thinking it may possibly be a CSS rule applied somewhere.

Comment: So you want every padding equally?

Comment: Yes if possible like the equal 20px padding that has been applied to the <label>, <h3> and button inside .well

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade bootstrap to 3.x??? Because your sample is a bit outdated.